# Enable Location Service on Facebook Messenger app for Samsung Galaxy Note II

Tags: samsung-galaxy-note-2, facebook-messenger, location-services

How do I enable location services on Facebook Messenger app for Samsung Galaxy Note II?

Answer (score 0):

Within the Messenger app, choose the Overflow menu (three vertical dots) then choose `Settings > Location Services` and check the box that enables location services for the app.

Comment: I tried but still it is disable.